# Query for restricting associated entities

Tags: sql, hibernate

I would like to form a query where an associated collection has been
restricted, ideally with Hibernate Criteria or HQL, but I'd be
interested in how to do this in SQL.  For example, say I have a Boy
class with a bidirectional one-to-many association to the Kites class.
I want to get a List of the Boys whose kites' lengths are in a range.

The problem is that the HQL/Criteria I know only gets me Boy objects
with a complete (unrestricted) Set of Kites, as given in these two
examples (the HQL is a guess).  I.e., I get the Boys who have Kites
in the right range, but for each such Boy I get *all* of the Kites, not
just the ones in the range.

```
select new Boy(name) from Boy b 
       inner join Kite on Boy.id=Kite.boyId 
             where b.name = "Huck" and length >= 1;

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Boy.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Huck"))
    .createCriteria("kites")
    .add(Restrictions.ge("length", new BigDecimal(1.0)));
List list = crit.list();
```

Right now the only way I have to get the correct Kite length Sets is
to iterate through the list of Boys and for each one re-query Kites
for the ones in the range.  I'm hoping some SQL/HQL/Criteria wizard
knows a better way.  I'd prefer to get a Criteria solution because my
real "Boy" constructor has quite a few arguments and it would be handy
to have the initialized Boys.

My underlying database is MySQL.  Do not assume that I know much about
SQL or Hibernate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is best done by reversing the join:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Kite.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.ge("length", new BigDecimal(1.0))
.createCriteria("boy")
.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Huck")));
List<Kite> list = crit.list();
```

Note that the list's Kites need to be aggregated into Boys, this
can be done easily with a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no hibernate expert, but as you say you're interested in the SQL solution as well...:

In SQL, I assume you mean something like (with the addition of indices, keys, etc):

```
CREATE TABLE Boys (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(16))
CREATE TABLE Kites(Length FLOAT, BoyID INT, Description TEXT)
```

plus of course other columns &c that don't matter here.

All boys owning 1+ kites with lenghts between 1.0 and 1.5:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Boys.*
FROM Boys
JOIN Kites ON(Kites.BoyID=Boys.ID AND Kites.Length BETWEEN 1.0 AND 1.5)
```

If you also want to see the relevant kites' description, with N rows per boy owning N such kites:

```
SELECT Boys.*, Kites.Length, Kites.Description
FROM Boys
JOIN Kites ON(Kites.BoyID=Boys.ID AND Kites.Length BETWEEN 1.0 AND 1.5)
```

Hope somebody can help you integrate these with hybernate...!

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent and got me thinking along the right lines.